# Read json in python after encoding it

Tags: python, json

I have a json file that fails loading when I use the following code:

```
indices_json_path = 'file.json'
with open(indices_json_path) as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
```

But if I manually open this file in notepad++ and click encode=>encode UTF-8, then save the file and re-run the code so everything works well. 
I would like to avoid manual repair. Any help?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: so it seams you write to file "with hands" not with json module )

Answer (score 1):

I would probably guess it is an encoding error, try:

```
import io
with io.open(indices_json_path,'r',encoding='utf8') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem:

```
with io.open(indices_json_path,'r', encoding='UTF-16-LE') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
```